# Download button of website which is loaded into webview doesnot work

Tags: android, html, webview

I am developing web based app contain list of images with download button. If user clicks on download, that image will be saved into his phone storage.
I have allowed Internet access and storage access. But didn't download after clicking download.

**Main activity.java:**

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.saveFr);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
wv.loadUrl("http://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-jpg-image.php");
```

In Manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am new to android development. 
Thanks for replies.

Comment: I think you you have implement setDownloadListener in webview

Comment: If you don't know much about the Android WebView, I would suggest to go with https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView. Safes you much pain

Comment: Thanks for reply and link